# How to remove false value when readonly widget fields no value, For Odoo11?

Tags: xml, widget, odoo, readonly

I have some fields with widget parameter in xml. And these fields are readonly, when no value inserted in these fields these always show false. So, how to remove false from these fields. I sharing my code as well as screenshot for this problem.

```
<group>
    <field name="partner_id" required="1"
           string="Customer"
           domain="[('customer', '=', True),('internal_user', '=', False)]"
           context="{'search_default_customer': 1,
            'default_name': partner_name, 'default_street': street,
            'default_street2': street2, 'default_city': city,
            'default_state_id': state_id, 'default_zip': zip,
            'default_country_id': country_id, 'default_function': function,
            'default_phone': phone, 'default_mobile': mobile,
            'default_email': email_from,
            'default_user_id': user_id, 'default_team_id': team_id, 'default_website': website}"/>

    <field name="email_from" string="Email" widget="email" readonly="1"/>    
    <field name="phone" widget="phone" readonly="1"/>
    <field name="website" widget="url" placeholder="e.g. www.sunarctechnologies.com"
       readonly="1"/>
</group>
```

[image]
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hmm. You can hide it when it is empty. Is this solution ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the python side with the "default" attribut doing for exemple `fields.Char(string=xxxx',default='xxx')`